# Are all race conditions worth fixing?

Tags: concurrency, delphi, philosophy

I just wrote the following piece of code (in delphi):

```
procedure Update(Value: Integer);
begin
  // If the last update was yesterday, replace yesterday value
  if CompareDate(FLastUpdate,Now) <> 0 then
  begin
    FYesterdayValue := FTodayValue;
  end;
  FTodayValue := Value;
  FLastUpdate := Now;
end;
```

And I realized that it contains a small, but real race condition. Imagine that the first time the "Now" function is called it's one millisecond before midnight, the if-statement is skipped and the timestamp is updated with another call to "Now" which is now one millisecond AFTER midnight. Now the timestamp has the wrong value and the FYesterdayValue will not get the correct value.

In practise, I think the chances of this ever happening is almost non existent because a) the code is typically called ~1 / minute and b) the cpu time between the two call will be EXTREMELY small.

However it's a bug and I'm curious if you would fix it if you stumbled upon it in a project.

Comment: Save the Now value in the beginning of the procedure. Use it consistently.

Comment: There are good arguments to make for either option (thus it is primarily opinion based), but I would make the change. I would make *one* call to `Now` and cache that value in a local variable, also to be sure that the value I check against is the same as what I store in `FLastUpdate`.

Comment: If it's practical to do so, refactor to pass in "Now". Now you can unit-test it, and you have no race condition.

Comment: I did fix it in the way Silviu suggested, it would have bothered me to hell if I didn't :) @Rory: Methinks that would break the abstraction created by this code!

Comment: +1 @Rory... The next step of @Rory's suggestion is to add a `now` parameter, and then create a wrapper function with the existing signature that calls the new signature, passing `Now`. That way you preserve the signature you want, but provide low-level control of the time value. That will make your life easier for unit testing, because you can specify exactly what the value of `now` is, and test the "midnight" scenario and other edge cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a general rule, problems are worth fixing when the expected benefit exceeds the expected cost. Thread safety is no exception from this rule, it's just that the way of calculating the risk that determines the expected cost is particularly complex and ill-understood by many.

To begin with, threading safety is not on many people's radar. They will simply assume "This is never called concurrently, nothing can go wrong". And often it isn't. Other times it is (e.g. the CPU stalled for an unexpectedly large time because the entire app now lives in an oversubscribed virtual machine...), and then nobody has any clue what could possibly have happened. In other words, the *probability* of a race actually occurring is often very hard to estimate.

The *impact* is often easier to understand: if you're logging some informative stuff to an internal audit log, it tends to be low; if the date that you're maintaining is related to business logic (perhaps it determines when the subscription licence of your customer expires?), then it might be catastrophically bad.

Without knowing the context of this code, I can't predict what should be done. But almost certainly it isn't a good idea to notice a possible race condition and do nothing about it by just convincing yourself that it won't be a problem. First, as I said, it is particularly hard to predict whether it will be a problem or not. Second, if the condition were probable, you would *have* to deal with it after all, so you *have* to be capable of securing your code. And if you understand how to do that (usually it isn't *that* hard), there is comparatively little reason not to do it all the time as a matter of principle - just to avoid convincing yourself "Ah, I don't need to worry in *this* instance, this will never happen", which is a classic example of "Famous last words".

Comment: I agree with this post, and I did fix it (as by storing Now initially). Making it thread safe would of course require further fixes and surely, not all code should be expected to be thread safe?! Instances of this class for example are in all cases owned by a single thread. As a side note, this code was only for statistics purposes so in any case the bug would be just annoying.

Comment: Not all code should be thread-safe, but you should have a definitive thread-safety *policy* for every part of your program that everyone acknowledges. "This is not expected to be used concurrently" is an excellent reason for ignoring race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

I would fix this bug, not just because of the race condition, but also because the version where you call `Now` once at the start and save it is much easier to reason about in general.

Basically, the more predictable a function is, the easier it is to understand. `Now` is, in a way, very unpredictable (it might return different values every time you call it), and thus every time you call it you make your own function less predictable and harder to understand.

As such, I really like Rory's suggestion that you refactor the call to `Now` out of the function completely. Now it's even more predictable, and as he points out, unit-testable.

Comment: I do not like the idea of passing Now as an argument. This would mean that the abstraction provided by this code would leak to clients.

Comment: There's a point to that, too. Another option would be to give the class a `Clock` member that can either be a real clock, or for the purpose of testing a fake clock.

Comment: Yes! That would fit with dependancy injection as well!